# C# - Can WebMethodAttribute adversely effect performance?

Tags: c#, web-services

I just noticed my Excel service running much faster.  I'm not sure if there is an environmental condition going on.  I did make a change to the method.  Where before it was

```
class WebServices{
[ WebMethod( /*...*/) ]
public string Method(){}
}
```

Now its attribute is removed and the method moved into another class

```
class NotWebService {
public string Method(){}
}
```

But, I did this because the Method is **not** called or used as a service.  Instead it was called via

```
WebServices service = new WebServices();
service.Method();
```

and inside the same assembly.  Now when I call the method

```
NotWebService notService = new NotWebService();
notService.Method();
```

The response time appears to have gone up.  Does the WebMethodAttribute have the potential to slow local calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the WebMethod attribute adds a lot of functionality in order to expose the method through a XML WebService.

Part of the functionality that causes **overhead** are the following features considered as part of the configurable stuff for a web method:

- BufferResponse
- CacheDuration
- Session Handling
- Transaction Handling

For more information just check the [WebMethod attribute documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but to avoid misinformation I feel the need to answer it anyway.

I disagree with wacdany's assessment.

A method marked as a webmethod should have no additional overhead if called directly as a method, rather than via HTTP. After all, it compiles to exactly the same intermediate language, other than the presence of a custom attribute.

Now adding a custom attribute can impact performace if it is one of the ones that is special to the compiler or runtime. WebMethodAttibute is neither.

I would next consider whether there is any special overhead to constructing the webservice object. If you have added a constructor there might be some, but by default there is no real overhead, since the constuctors of the base classes are trivial.

Therefore if you really were calling the method directly, there should be no real overhead, despite it also being accesable as a web service action. If you experienced a significant difference, it would be wise to verify if you were constructing the real `WebServices` class, and not somehow inadvetently using a web service proxy, perhaps due to adding a web service reference to your project.